# Running a simple_3dviz script on macOS Big Sur getting modernGL error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, macos-big-sur, python-moderngl

I try to run a `simple_3dviz` script, but I always get the following error:

```
File "...venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moderngl/context.py", line 1228, in program
    res.mglo, ls1, ls2, ls3, ls4, ls5, res._subroutines, res._geom, res._glo = self.mglo.program(
moderngl.error.Error: cannot create program
```

I have already installed `PyOpenGL` and `PyOpenGL-accelerate`, but the error stays the same.

My Python script:

```py
from simple_3dviz import Mesh
from simple_3dviz.window import show
from simple_3dviz.utils import render

...

show(
    Mesh.from_voxel_grid(voxels=workpiece.voxels),
    light=(-1,-1,1)
)
```